# how to build app for windows phone using sencha cmd?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, sencha-touch-2

I have build an app using sencha touch for android platforms but now I want to test it on windows phone. I have installed WP SDK and added platform wp8 in my app.
Please help me how to do it...

Comment: Did u even research about the same? IMHO, you should first research about the building app's, try some samples and then if you face some problem, come to SO :)

Comment: Yes i have done a lot.. and build apps for android devices,.. but in windows i am not able to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and found that you have to add `"wp8"` to `builds.native.cordova.config.platforms` in your `app.json` file.